# Shrink all images in pages document

Tags: macos, ms-office, pages, image-editing, image-capture

I have a *huge* (filesize) pages document, which I suspect is due to all the images in it.

The images were copied from elsewhere and pasted in.

A lot of the images are original resolutions of 1080 *minimum* (in most cases higher)

However, in the new document they obviously don't need to be that large.

Is there a way for me to reduce the document's filesize by limiting the images' sizes?

I hope you can understand what I mean.

(I need to be able to convert this to a word document afterwards if that matters)

Answer (score 1):

Preview can reduce the file size though you don't have much control over exactly what it does and how. For that you may need a purpose-built PDF editing tool, or Adobe Acrobat Standard or Pro.

Open the file in preview and then go FILE > DUPLICATE. A new identical window will open. Now save the new file and from the Quartz Filter menu select CompressPDF. Give your document a different name or location and click save.

Depending on what is going on in your PDF you should get a smaller file. But again you will have better control over the process with one of Adobe's Acrobat products or one of the third party PDF tools available for the Mac.